# Can an experiment done on casual cannabis users provide evidence for the risk of psychosis in long term users?

Tags: medical-science, recreational-drugs, marijuana

There is [an episode](https://www.documentaryarea.tv/video/Cannabis:%20Miracle%20Medicine%20or%20Dangerous%20Drug/) of [BBC Horizon](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m0007zly) with the title [Cannabis: Miracle Medicine or Dangerous Drug?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Horizon_(British_TV_series)_episodes#Series_55:_2019), presented by [Dr Javid Abdelmoneim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javid_Abdelmoneim).

During the documentary Abdelmoneim meets [Dr Amir Englund](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/people/amir-englund), a scientist who is conducting a research to developer safer types of recreational cannabis. He is then the subject of an experiment testing in separate dates four different compositions of THC and CBD. The experiment involves the study of the thoughts and the feelings of the subject during the high and the investigation of any sign of psychotic behaviour through some psychiatric tests.

During the first test the presenter (at about 29 mins) says

> I am beginning to think this is a trick on my patience

Then the scientist says that the presenter is becoming a bit suspicious. Then the presenter says

> You are tricking me

This was judged by the scientist as a an event of paranoid behaviour.

During the second test the presenter (at about 34 mins) says

> this times I am a lot more mellow

During the final review (at about 54-56 mins) this test was judged positively for the absence of paranoid behaviour.

During the final review it was also explained that the cannabis used for the first test had no CBD, only THC, while the cannabis used for the second had three times as much CBD as THC.

At the end of the documentary (57m45), Abdelmoneim claims:

> Amir's study suggests that it *is* possible to make recreational cannabis safer.

Can the results of that experiment give a clue on how to address the risks of psychosis? I understood that the risk of psychosis was related to the [long term use of cannabis](https://nida.nih.gov/publications/research-reports/marijuana/there-link-between-marijuana-use-psychiatric-disorders) and I also thought that it was caused by the fact that the long term use reduced the inner capacity of activating the neuro-receptors, thus increasing anxiety and similar conditions when the person is not under the effect of cannabis.

If so, the thoughts developed during a high have nothing to do with it. Serious research aimed at reducing the risks of recreational cannabis should test the *long term* effect on the neuro-receptors, not the effects of one or few highs on some individuals who are not regular users.

What I would like to know is if the documentary misrepresenting how cannabis might cause psychosis and how it could be prevented. This could be broken down in two questions:

- Could adjusting THC and CBD ratios in recreational cannabis lower the risk of psychosis?
- Can an experiment done on a number of casual users, that mainly studies the subjects behaviour during the high, be used as an evidence for the possible effects on long term users when they are not on a high?

This question is focused on the second point.

Comment: Of course the question has merit and I don't want to talk it down, but on a meta level I find it rather funny: "If we change the concentrations of active ingredients in a drug, do the side effects change?"

Comment: related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/54428/is-the-video-of-a-person-reducing-the-tremor-cause-by-parkinson-with-cannabis-sh

Comment: Link to [full study by Dr. Amir Englund](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/365430505_Does_cannabidiol_make_cannabis_safer_A_randomised_double-blind_cross-over_trial_of_cannabis_with_four_different_CBDTHC_ratios) (ResearchGate).

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I see that the abstract states that the study produced no evidence. It means that in a documentary seen by million of people they let them think something then in a paper that few thousands people will read they say the opposite. Not nice, but in any case it does not matter, because the question is about the validity of the methods employed in the study, not about the study results.

Comment: @mustermax: That is not a fair summary. The documentary was shown in 2019, and showed Englund *conducting experiments*. The quoted paper was released 3 months ago, presumably with some results of those experiments. The main claim about CBD ratios affecting long-term psychosis came from Dr Marta Di Forti, not Englund, whose claims I quoted and you edited out for unclear reasons.

Comment: This is not the same question it was when I upvoted yesterday. Removed my upvote.

Comment: @JeromeViveiros this is the question I asked. Oddthinking edits turned it into another question, I restored the original question. The reason I left the breakdown at the end is to show the question that Oddthinking wanted to ask and to point out that it is a different question.

Comment: "an experiment done on casual cannabis users provide[s] evidence for the risk of psychosis in long term users" could you clarify whereabouts in the documentary that specific claim is made. At the moment, it just seems to be a question you're asking because you're interested, this is not the site for that. We challenge notable, unreferenced claims made in the various media which are widely believed - can you make it clear where that specific claim is being made, where it is explicitly stated (not just your interpretation of what they say, but *that actual claim*).

Comment: @mustermax I'm sorry then, but anecdotally I know three people who suffer from cannabis-induced psychosis. One is my cousin, and one an old friend, and both suffer from schizophrenia. The third person was in a sober house with me after rehab, and he is fine. (I was there for something else.) So I upvoted because I found the edited question interesting, as in how to reduce the risk of psychosis. I'm not skeptical about it being a potential trigger for psychosis.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. The claim is that the experiment as it is shown in the documentary can provide some clue to make cannabis less dangerous. From what I see it does not seem a valid experiment for the declared purpose.

Comment: I get that it's an interesting and important question to know the answer to, but scientific scepticism (or skepticism in US-speak) relies on being precise about what's claimed. I'm not disagreeing that the documentary is suggestive that there might be implications which fit with your question, but what is actually stated? Could you edit in the *exact* quote that's to be challenged, else we're just challenging interpretations, which is more about media-studies or even literary criticism than what we do here.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the point of quoting the vague claim from a TV show, when you could use their paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41386-022-01478-z

Comment: And regarding your other understandings, "THC can cause acute impairments in memory and attention and psychotic symptoms among infrequent users." according to this paper. Although checking the first paper they cited for that it only says "resemble some aspects of endogenous psychoses". So I suspect even that is being debated.

Comment: ... because the 2nd paper they cite on that says "These findings confirm that THC can induce a transient, acute psychotic reaction in psychiatrically well individuals."

Comment: @Fizz *"I'm not sure what is the point of quoting the vague claim from a TV show, when you could use their paper"* Please see my comment to JiminyCricket